# Can my wife join me (I have a Tier 4 student visa) for a month from India using a tourist visa?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens

I am in the UK on a tier 4 student visa. I recently got married and would like my wife to join me for the month of June. Can she apply for a general tourist visa to visit me?

If that would not work, what sort of visa would be most appropriate for her to get?

Comment: Why wouldn't she be able to apply ? A general visitor visa should do

Answer (score 3):

To visit you under the terms and conditions of [Appendix V of the Immigration Rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules), your spouse can apply as a [Standard Visitor](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/overview).

To do this your spouse can open an account at [Visa4UK](https://www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk/home/welcome) and create an application that looks like this...

[image]

Source: Screen capture of the application

And then explain that her husband is a student and this is the premise of her visit.  In order for her to apply as a *family visitor*, you would need to be settled in the UK ([have ILR](https://www.gov.uk/settle-in-the-uk) or British nationality) and so you do not qualify.  If she selects "*family visitor*" the application will fork to a questionnaire about who qualifies and it's difficult to back out to the starting place again.

Regardless of where her application is submitted, it will be sent to one of the decision-making hubs shown in this exhibit...

[image]

Source: UKVI [Hub and Spoke](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/list-of-home-office-international-hub-and-spoke-centres) Presentation